# Are all denominators of $\zeta(2n)$ abundant, for $n\geq2$?

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta, divisor-sum

Consider the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(n)$ defined for positive integers $n$ as usual by:

$$
\zeta (n)=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac {1}{k^{n}}}.
$$

For positive even numbers we have the identity:

$$
{\displaystyle A_{n}\zeta (2n)=B_{n}\pi ^{2n}\,\!},
$$

where the sequence $A_n$ ($A002432$ in the OEIS) represents the denominators in $\zeta(2s)$. Then I propose the following conjecture:

> **Conjecture 1**. For all $n\geq2$, $A_n$ is abundant.

Is this known? Is there an explanation for this? I have verified the conjecture for $2\leq n \leq 17$.

Comment: Hint: $\zeta(2n)=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{B_{2n}(2\pi)^{2n}}{2(2n)!}$.

Comment: Further hint: the [Von-Staudt-Clausen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Staudt%E2%80%93Clausen_theorem) gives the denominator of $B_{2n}$ in a explicit way: it is the product of primes $p$ such that $(p-1)\mid (2n)$.